# Unable to figure out rhino mocks issue

Tags: rhino-mocks

In a method in presenter,I expect a method of view to be called.This method is also passed data extracted from a service method(which is not mocked).This service method basically gets data from database and returns List(using LINQ to SQL).Now, when I write this in the test

```
 List<customers> cus = expecteddata;
 view.AssertWasCalled(v => v.InitializeCustomersForSelectedCity(cus));      

Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException:   ICustomerListView.InitializeCustomersForSelectedCity(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DAL.Customer]); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

The code which I am testing in presenter

```
  public void HandleSelectedCity(int City)
    {
        selectedCity = City ;
        _custometListForm.InitializeCustomersForSelectedCity(_CustomerListService.GetActiveCustomersForSelectedCity(selectedCity));            
    }
```

When I ignore arguments, test works fine
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assertion creates an expectation based on `cus`, a variable defined in the unit test. However, when InitializeCustomersForSelectedCity is invoked, it's being invoked with the result of GetActiveCustomersForSelectedCity - a different instance of `List<customers>`.

Expectations setups basically perform an `object.Equals` operation on the expected instance and the actual instance. In your case, they are different, and the expectaction is not satisfied.

Either you need to loosen your expectation to accept any `List<customers>`, or you need to mock GetActiveCustomersForSelectedCity as well so that you can define the returned result from the unit test.

Comment: ok thanks.I decided to split the test into 2 - one an interaction test, method was called.And, another test for the service method